# 500 Response From Heroku App

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have recently deployed a small app I am developing to Heroku. Everything was working as expected until I updated the code to make use of flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy and Heroku's PostgreSQL. Once I followed [these instructions](http://blog.y3xz.com/blog/2012/08/16/flask-and-postgresql-on-heroku/) I updated the code in my `items()` method to populate the page with data and post using the database. Now whenever I navigate to the items page I receive a 500 response.

I'm quite sure that it's the code I added to make use of the DB as the other pages in the app work fine. They are coded in the exact same way as the items page originally was using a dictionary instead of a database. It also runs fine on my local machine just not on Heroku.

items():

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from forms import *
from models import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
app.secret_key = 'secret_shhhhh!@#$1234'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/items', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def items():
    form = ItemForm()
    item_list = db.session.query(Item).all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('items.html', form=form, item_list=item_list)
    else:
        if form.validate():
            new_item = Item(form.sku.data, form.title.data)
            db.session.add(new_item)
            db.session.commit()
            form.sku.data = ''
            form.title.data = ''
            item_list = db.session.query(Item).all()
            return render_template('items.html', form=form, item_list=item_list, item_added=True)
        else:
            return render_template('items.html', form=form, item_list=item_list, item_added=False)


@app.route('/shelves', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def shelves():
    form = ShelfForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('shelves.html', form=form, test_shelf_dict=test_shelf_dict)
    else:
        if form.validate():
            test_shelf_dict[form.name.data] = form.name.data
            form.name.data = ''
            return render_template('shelves.html', form=form, test_shelf_dict=test_shelf_dict, shelf_added=True)
        else:
            return render_template('shelves.html', form=form, test_shelf_dict=test_shelf_dict, shelf_added=False)
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
Flask-WTF==0.9.4
Jinja2==2.7.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
SQLAlchemy==0.9.1
WTForms==1.0.5
Werkzeug==0.9.4
argparse==1.2.1
gunicorn==18.0
itsdangerous==0.23
psycopg2==2.5.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

updated Heroku logs

```
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-01-18 21:51:10 [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/flasktest.py", line 17
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]:     app.config[debug=True]
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073395+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]:                     ^
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073623+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-01-18T21:51:10.074297+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/flasktest.py", line 17
2014-01-18T21:51:10.074297+00:00 app[web.1]:                     ^
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-01-18T21:51:10.074297+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2014-01-18T21:51:10.074297+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-01-18T21:51:10.073781+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-01-18T21:51:10.074297+00:00 app[web.1]:     app.config[debug=True]
2014-01-18T21:51:10.074297+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-01-18 21:51:10 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2014-01-18T21:51:10.197186+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-01-18 21:51:10 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2014-01-18T21:51:10.197025+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-01-18 21:51:10 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-01-18T21:51:11.464431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-18T21:51:11.448083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2014-01-18T21:51:18.281373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/items host=glacial-spire-3650.herokuapp.com request_id=612d0d1e-4a04-46f0-b96f-5ddbdb420e78 fwd="24.164.177.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

UPDATED: After configuring the error logging and debugging properly, I believe this is the root of the problem:

```
2014-01-19T04:00:34.648038+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM item
2014-01-19T04:00:34.648038+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:flasktest:(ProgrammingError) relation "item" does not exist  # This line right here
```

Here is the code for my model, and I believe the error message is referencing the first line inside my model:

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'  # I believe this is the relation that doesn't exist
    item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    sku = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    title = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, sku, title):
        self.sku = sku
        self.title = title
```

Comment: Did you try putting Flask into debug mode? The page should render with a traceback.

Comment: Do you have a repo where we can review the code?

Comment: github repo - https://github.com/im-auld/Flask_Inventory_Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much Googling I have determined the issue to be the `item` table not being created. I have fixed the problem however it's not my preferred way of doing it. By changing my model and moving it to my main file everything behaves as expected:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from forms import *
from models import Bin, Shelf, BinItem
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
import logging
import sys


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
app.secret_key = 'secret_shhhhh!@#$1234'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    item_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    sku = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, sku, title):
        self.sku = sku
        self.title = title

@app.route('/items', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def items():
    try:
        log.info('Start reading form DB')
        form = ItemForm()
        item_list = db.session.query(Item).all()
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('items.html', form=form, item_list=item_list)
        else:
            if form.validate():
                new_item = Item(form.sku.data, form.title.data)
                db.session.add(new_item)
                db.session.commit()
                form.sku.data = ''
                form.title.data = ''
                item_list = db.session.query(Item).all()
                return render_template('items.html', form=form, item_list=item_list, item_added=True)
            else:
                return render_template('items.html', form=form, item_list=item_list, item_added=False)
    except:
        _, ex, _ = sys.exc_info()
        log.error(ex.message)
```

I would rather have the models in a separate file. I have tried a few things to achieve that but none of them have worked.

- declaring `db =SQLAlchemy(app)` in the `models` file, modifying the `Item` class to match the above and importing `db` into my main file.
- Modifying the `Item` class to match the above and importing `db` from the main file into `models`

On both occasions the `heroku logs` command informed me that `db` could not be imported.

I am going to mark the question as answered since it is now working the way I want and will open another question to see how I can move the class definitions to another file and still have everything work.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html):

> The Web server (running the Web Site) encountered an unexpected
> condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request by the
> client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) for
> access to the requested URL.
>
> This is a 'catch-all' error generated by the Web server. Basically
> something has gone wrong, but the server can not be more specific
> about the error condition in its response to the client. In addition
> to the 500 error notified back to the client, the Web server should
> generate some kind of internal error log which gives more details of
> what went wrong. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to
> locate and analyse these logs. (Last updated: October 2013)

If you're ok with it, set the [flask app to debug](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode) and also add some logging.  [Heroku logs gather stdout from your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#what-happens-to-data-written-to-standard-out), so just log to stdout inside the `except` block of a `try:`/`except:`.   Next, add some error handling to your code so that you can determine the point of failure.  Lastly, add some `INFO`-level logging to explain what's going on that you can turn off when you're not investigating problems.

Here's an example of some easy Python logging configuration to stdout:

```
import logging
import sys

# Defaults to stdout
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# get the logger for the current Python module
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try: 

    log.info('Start reading database')
    # do risky stuff

except:

    # http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html
    _, ex, _ = sys.exc_info()
    log.error(ex.message)
```

Comment: Updated the heroku log data

Comment: Seems like using `app.run(debug=True, ...)` is where is having problems.  Try setting that just after you create the app, near where you're configuring it.

Comment: As an aside, queries to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/items` work just fine, provided that there's a try/except around the db query.  I have a feeling this is a Heroku-specific quirk.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine on my local machine, I only encounter th problem once deployed to Heroku.

Comment: +1000 - Of all the answers I found, this was the only one that properly logged to Heroku's log system